# Change different header styles at different scroll positions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, header

I am trying to make a header for a website where the header changes to different colors at different positions on the page.

Trying to get blue color background for header if the page is scrolled down with less than 40 pixels. And then red color background for header if the page is scrolled down between 40 pixels and 100 pixels. And then when the page is moved completely up, the header background is a yellow color.

Edit 1:
In short, Trying to make a sticky header change colors at different positions of the scroll on a page.

Edit 2:
Tried a new way of putting conditions. Updated the below code with latest working sticky header.
My problem is, when the header goes to the top position, it doesn't change back to orange color

So far I have got this code.
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gq5ntzhs/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var mywindow = $(window);
var transoffset = $('#stickyheaders').offset().top;
var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
mywindow.scroll(function() {
if (mypos > 40) {
if(mywindow.scrollTop() > mypos)
{
$('#stickyheaders').addClass('headerup');
}
else
{
  if(mywindow.scrollTop() < 155) {
    $('#stickyheaders').addClass('headertranspup');
  } else {
//$('#stickyheaders').removeClass('headerup');
$('#stickyheaders').addClass('headerstyleup');
  }
}
}
mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
});
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }

section { 
  height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 100px; }
  
  #stickyheaders{
    background: orange;
-webkit-transition: transform 0.34s ease;
transition : transform 0.34s ease;
}
.headerup{
position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange !important;
//transform: translateY(-110px);
//adjust this value to the height of your header
}
.headerstyleup{
    background-color: blue !important;
}
.headertranspup{
    background-color: red !important;
}
.headertranpup{
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div id="stickyheaders">This div will stick to the top</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Explain the problem you are facing.

Comment: Just added the edit saying in simplest terms of the result I want to achieve.

Comment: Your header is not sticky, and it does change color...

Comment: Just added new edit to the original post. Hope my problem is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for a problem like this is by assigning background-colour to the header directly in the element property using jquery rather than adding a new class with the same css property like background-colour in this case.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var mywindow = $(window);
var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
mywindow.scroll(function() {
if (mypos > 40) {
if(mywindow.scrollTop() > mypos)
{
$('#stickyheaders').addClass('headerup');
//$('#stickyheaders').addClass('headertranpup');
$('#stickyheaders').css("background-color","orange");
}
else
{
if(mywindow.scrollTop() < 75) {
$('#stickyheaders').removeClass('headerup');
$('#stickyheaders').css("background-color","transparent");
}
else
{
$('#stickyheaders').css("background-color","blue");
}
}
}
mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
});
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }

section { 
  height: 2000px;
  padding-top: 100px; }
  
  #stickyheaders{
-webkit-transition: transform 0.34s ease;
transition : transform 0.34s ease;
}
.headerup{
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  width: 100%;
adjust this value to the heigt of your header*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div id="stickyheaders">This div will stick to the top</div>
</section>
```